# Json.Net Serialize String from URI

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

Currently I'm using a web request to get the body of a webpage which is strictly json.

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("urihere");
            string text;
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

Now that I've got the string of json in a variable I'm trying to figure out how to parse that data. I'm attempting to use json.net as below:

```
User primaryuser = new Models.User();
            primaryuser.FullName = "Test";

            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            serializer.Converters.Add(new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
            serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("filenamehere"))
            using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, primaryuser);
            }
```

Naturally when I try to pass a uri into the streamwriter I get a "uri not supported" error.

**What is the proper way to map this data from a uri using json.net?**

Comment: how does the URI looks like? if you are getting "URI format not supported" try `new Uri(path).LocalPath`

Comment: http://uri/sub/ and the json is in the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serializing and deserializing an object in Json.net:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(primaryuser, Formatting.Indented);
User primaryuser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);
```

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm